# Negspacy for different entity types in the same spacy pipeline?

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have a spacy pipeline with NER component, and for the NER component, I have also added a negspacy component so I can detect negations of the detected entities. The NER detects two entity types, DISEASE and CHEMICAL. I want to create separate negation detection rules for each entity type. Not sure how to do that.

```
## Load the medical NER model
## this model identifies two types of entities -- disease (such as headache) and chemical (drug name such as iburprofen)
nlp=spacy.load('en_ner_bc5cdr_md')  ##this model is only compatible with latest versions of spacy

### the following negation rules only apply to DISEASE entity

nlp.add_pipe("negex", 
    config={
            "neg_termset":{
            "pseudo_negations": ["might not", 'not report', 'not recall'],
            "preceding_negations": ["not",  "denies", 'denied', "no", 'refused', 'never',  'refuses', 'deny', 'negative', 'neg',  'declined'],
            "following_negations":["declined", "0/10", '0 out of 10'],
            "termination": ["but", "however"]
        },
        
        "ent_types":["DISEASE"]
        
    }
             
    )
```

Is it possible to create separate negation rules for CHEMICAL entity?